# Render element in repeater conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm tring to render items to page where I want to have five items per row. This means I want to have div element with row class only rendered every five items in array. Here is little pseudo code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="row"> // render only every five items
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>// render at all times
    </div>
</div>
```

How is this possible to do in angular? I already looked into ng-if and ng-show directives but these seem to hide also nested html elements which is something I do not want. This did not work for me: `ng-if="$index % 5 == 0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I eded up doing, to render five items per row I iterate two times trough the array and I render items conditionaly.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="($index % 5 == 0)"> 
   <div ng-repeat="item in items.slice($index, $index+5)">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the `class="row"` attribute you can use something like this:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'row': $index % 5 === 0 }">
```

Comment: Hmmm, I've misunderstood your initial question... Why do you want to render the `<div class="row">` only every 5 items? Is it because the `class="row"` attribute?

Comment: yes its because of the attribute, but also div element will cause ui to render each item as individual row so the div must not be there. I might have to rethink my row class css, but I thought I could use some condition which could omit the element itself not just its attribute

Answer (score 0):

**Using a directive**

Plunkr @ http://plnkr.co/edit/iNBIWFrszqfT6Y057Bck

```
angular.module('treesApp', [])
        .controller('treeController', function ($scope) {
        console.log('AppCtrl started..');
        $scope.user = 'test';
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 1"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 2"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 3"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 4"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 5"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 6"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 7"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 8"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 9"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 10"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 11"});
        $scope.items.push({name:"item 12"});
    })
        .directive('sectionedList', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
              items: '=items',
            },
            template: '<div ng-repeat="item in treeItems"><div class="row"><h3>{{item.name}}</h3>' +
              '<div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="leaf in item.leaves">{{leaf.name}}</div>' +
              '</row></div>',
            link: function($scope) {
              $scope.treeItems = [];
              for (i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; ++i) {
                if(i % 5 == 0) {
                  console.log('root: ' + i);
                  var len = $scope.treeItems.push($scope.items[i]);
                  $scope.treeItems[len-1].leaves = [];
                } else {
                  var parent = Math.floor(i/5);
                  console.log('root with leave: ' + parent + ' - ' + i);
                  $scope.treeItems[parent].leaves.push($scope.items[i]);
                }
              }

              console.log($scope.treeItems);
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {

            }

        }
    })
```

-- OLD EDIT ---

You could use `ng-show` and pass in `$index%5 == 0` as per the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Will not that also hide nested elements?

Comment: Apologies yes it will (didn't read full question) - in that case I think you may need a directive.

Comment: Ok so how do I render elemnt every n items with directive?

Answer (score 0):

Think you need a dynamic class determined by there orders:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="{{{true:'row', false:''}[$index%5==0]}}"> // class judge by code block.
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>// render at all times
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work div elemet will cause to break my UI because it will render aech item as a new row